# there any way to make my app run after convert it from python script to desktop app

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyinstaller

I make gui game with python and when I convert it - using pyinstaller package - from python script to descktop app isn't work I click double click and nothing happen how can I slove this problem ?

> This code also rise the same problem:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk ()
root.config (bg="black ")
#=========================
Label  (root , text = "Hi" ,bg= "blue" , fg ="green").grid()
#=========================
root.mainloop()
```

when I convert this code the same problem happen.

Comment: please create [example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine for me: steps I took

**OS**: Windows   |      **Terminal**: Git

1. `mkdir folder`
2. `cd folder`
3. `python -m venv venv`
4. `venv\Scripts\activate`
5. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip pyinstaller`
6. open new file `app.py` and paste your example into file
7. `pyinstaller -F --noconsole app.py`
8. `cd dist`
9. `app.exe`  <--- opens the window and all works fine

Comment: Any time I want convert  script I showld do the same steps ?

Comment: yes its a good place to start

Comment: sorry to say that but this way run just in first times

Comment: What do you mean it only runs the first time?

Comment: I mean that when I code other app and convert it to exe isn't run

Comment: @BOUHDYD_X if you post the code for that app then I could probably figure out what is wrong